# Pivoting streaming dataframes without aggregation in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

| ID | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | car | camry |
| A | price | 20000 |
| B | car | tesla |
| B | price | 40000 |

Example dataframe that is being streamed.

I need output to look like this. Anyone have suggestions?

| ID | car | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | camry | 20000 |
| B | tesla | 40000 |

Whats a good way to transform this? I have been researching pivoting but it requires an aggregation which is not something I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter the frame (`df`) twice, and join

```
(
    df.filter(df.type=="car").withColumnRenamed("value","car")
    .join(
        df.filter(df.type=="price").withColumnRenamed("value","price")
        , on="ID"
    )
    .select("ID", "car", "price")
)
```